# How to convert HTML to plain text

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How can I convert one field from html (generated with CKEdit) to normal plain text?
The HTML is

**Line1boldanditalics**

"Line2" simple

**Line3justbold**

I have tried:

```
1)
$title = drupal_html_to_text($title);
$title = str_replace('*', '',$title);
$title = str_replace('/', '',$title);
$title = str_replace("&quot;", "\"",$title);
```

but I can't really remove the quotes, the last line does not seem to work.

2)  html_entity_decode() instead
then I get all the <p&gt...Line1
3) I tried to parse it myself and remove via str_replace and preg_replace, but that's a bit more complicated.

The html can contain only the following tags: p strong> em

How can I get to 
Line1boldanditalics "Line2" simple Line3justbold

Thank you